# ensuring execution order when using Typescript modules

Tags: typescript, es6-modules

I am trying to add an in-memory shim of indexedDB so that tests run in Node.

Currently I have 2 modules:

```js
import Dexie from 'dexie';
export class DrugsDBLocal extends Dexie { ...
```

fake-indexedDb polyfills appropriate indexedDB functions like:

```js
var globalVar = typeof window !== "undefined" ? window : // self, global etc.
globalVar.indexedDB = fakeIndexedDB;
globalVar.IDBCursor = FDBCursor;
// nothing exported
```

Test:

```js
import 'fake-indexeddb/auto';
import { DrugsDBLocal } from '@/...DrugsLocalDb';
describe('setup local db', () => {
    const db = new DrugsDBLocal(fileFetch, new EmptyLogger());
```

The problem is that Dexie is executing before the polyfill has run. Obviously I do not wish to put an import in the DrugsDBLocal module, as the polyfill should not be present on the browser. The tests are being transpiled from typescript using webpack (as a vue-cli project), and the conglomerated file is placing the code from 'fake-indexeddb/auto' *below* the Dexie library.

How do I ensure the empty 'fake-indexeddb/auto' import is executed first?

**Edit**
Vue cli builds a new webpack.config.js each test run. I think I need to define a new entry as in [this webpack reference](https://webpack.js.org/guides/shimming/#loading-polyfills). I have tried the following with no success

```
module.exports = {
  pages: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'test' ? void 0 : {
    testPolyfills:'./tests/test_resources/testPolyfills.js'
  },
  chainWebpack: config => {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test') {
      config.entry('app').add('./src/main.ts');
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try if switching to `require` works:

```
require('fake-indexeddb/auto');
const localDb = require('@/...DrugsLocalDb');

describe('setup local db', () => {
    const db = new localDb.DrugsDBLocal(fileFetch, new EmptyLogger());
```

Comment: tried and it didn't work, but thanks for the suggestion